# Hosting an MVC6 application under default website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-hosting, asp.net-core-mvc

I have hosted many ASP.NET and MVC applications before. I was playing with MVC6 lately and tried to host an MVC6 application.

Everything works fine if I host it as a new website. When I host it as an application under the default website of IIS, it only shows an empty page. Please find the log information below

> warn:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
>         Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when
>   application exits. warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[0]
>         Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage. Hosting environment: Production Now listening on:
>   http://localhost:23000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/MVC6   info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
>         Request finished in 0.0687ms 404

**Note**: Default website uses application pool **asp.net4.5** and my MVC6 application uses it's own application pool as mentioned in http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#iis-server-configuration

Anyone else faced similar problem like this? I want to know how to make it work under default website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This is a bug in vs2015 rc1 https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/416#issuecomment-149046552.

There is a workaround for this bug in above link but I followed a different method because **I need to host my application in more than one website without republishing**.

I resolved the above problem using the **Route** attribute. After adding the route attribute to an action result, application works fine

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("MVC6")]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }    
    }
```